# RxJS multiple switchMap and map operators... is there a better way?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm pretty new to RxJS and am wondering if I am doing this right... in the ngOnInit() function below, I get a client object, then pipe it...

Is there a better way to do the repeat switchMap/map operations below?

My code works... but I am wondering if there is a more elegant approach that I should be adopting...

```js
 public client: Client;
 public contract: Contract;      
 public alreadyPendingContract: boolean;
 public alreadyActiveContract: boolean;
 public minimumStartDate: Date;
 public minimumEndDate: Date;
 public rolloverExclusionDate: Date;
 public startDateFilter;
 
 ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.getClient$().pipe(
      filter(client => client != null),
      map(client => this.client = client),
      pluck('client_id'),
      map((client_id: string) => {
        this.clientContractForm.get('client_id').setValue(client_id);
        return client_id;
      }),
      switchMap((client_id: string) => {
        return this.contractAddService.getAlreadyPendingContract$(client_id);
      }),
      map(alreadyPendingContract => {
        this.alreadyPendingContract = alreadyPendingContract;
        return this.client.client_id;
      }),
      switchMap((client_id: string) => {
        return this.contractAddService.getAlreadyActiveContract$(client_id);
      }),
      map(alreadyActiveContract => {
        this.alreadyActiveContract = alreadyActiveContract;
      }),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.contractAddService.getMinimumStartDate$(this.client.client_id);
      }),
      map((minimumStartDate: IMinimumStartDate) => {
        this.minimumStartDate = minimumStartDate.minimumStartDate;
        this.rolloverExclusionDate = minimumStartDate.rolloverExclusionDate;
        this.startDateFilter = (m: Moment): boolean => {
          // Filters out the rollover exclusion day from being an available start date.
          return !moment.utc(m).isSame(moment.utc(this.rolloverExclusionDate), 'day');
        }
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: your `switchMap`s are following one another sequentially when (it seems to me) they could be run in parallel with some sort of `flatMap`. They all use only client id as input, so it could be just a set of *parallel* calls

Comment: I see nothing wrong with you code, what do you mean by a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is more elegant, but it is an alternative way

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.getClient$().pipe(
      filter(client => client != null),
      map(client => {
         this.client = client;
         this.clientContractForm.get('client_id').setValue(client_id);
         return client.client_id;
      },
      switchMap(client_id => this.doStuffWithClientId(client_id)),
      map((minimumStartDate: IMinimumStartDate) => {
        this.minimumStartDate = minimumStartDate.minimumStartDate;
        this.rolloverExclusionDate = minimumStartDate.rolloverExclusionDate;
        this.startDateFilter = (m: Moment): boolean => {
          // Filters out the rollover exclusion day from being an available start date.
          return !moment.utc(m).isSame(moment.utc(this.rolloverExclusionDate), 'day');
        }
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }

doStuffWithClientId(clientId: string) {
   return this.contractAddService.getAlreadyPendingContract$(client_id).pipe(
      tap(alreadyPendingContract => this.alreadyPendingContract = alreadyPendingContract),
      switchMap(() => this.contractAddService.getAlreadyActiveContract$(clientId)),
      tap(alreadyActiveContract => this.alreadyActiveContract = alreadyActiveContract),
      switchMap(() => this.contractAddService.getMinimumStartDate$(clientId)),
   )
}
```

I have not tested the code, so there may well be syntax mistakes. The basic idea though is to isolate all the things which depend on `client_id` into one function which receives the *clientId* as input and therefore makes it visible throughout the entire function.

Comment: hello @Picci, goal of map pipe is to transform original input, not to store value in attribute or any traitment. Please prefer using `tap` pipe who are design for that.